# running selenium tests on teamcity on 2 agents at the same time throws error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration, automated-tests, teamcity, webdriver-io

So me and my colleagues are trying to run on our Teamcity CI our UI tests at the same time.

What happens is if he starts running his tests before me on one build agent when I start mine on other Agent I get:

```
     'selenium' errored after 1.63 s
Error: Selenium exited before it could start
at ChildProcess.errorIfNeverStarted (D:\TC\Smith\work\dbf31e6f7e500354\node_modules\selenium-standalone\lib\start.js:128:15)
 at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
 at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:204:12)
```

Both Agents are on the same Virtual maschine and we both use chrome and chrome driver to run our tests (JS tests with selenium).

Anyone has Idea how to run them at the same time, not to wait for each other?